# Normal https://webchat.botframework.com stopped working in IE 10. syntax error webchat-es5.js

Tags: botframework, web-chat

I am using sdk v4 bot embedded in sharepoint 2016 page using iframe webchat https://webchat.botframework.com/embed/[Token] url. It stopped working in IE 10. I remember it worked before 3 weeks. Please help as we put the bot in production.

Answer (score 0):

There was a recent update to webchat, so I'm guessing this is a webchat version issue. Do you have the ability to use directline channel with [botframework-webchat](https://github.com/microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat) instead? There are a number of samples. In the getting-started [full-bundle](https://github.com/microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat/tree/master/samples/01.getting-started/a.full-bundle) sample, you can see where the latest version is specified. You can use this to specify a later version, though I'm not sure if it will let you go far enough back.

You are also going to need to customize the formatting, as the new webchat comes through with essentially no formatting. There are a number of samples on that site showing the different formatting options as well.

For shorter term fix, you may be able to request your specific bot app ID to be reverted by contacting the Microsoft contact from this [github issue](https://github.com/microsoft/BotFramework-Services/issues/175), though I would recommend also working on updating your implementation as that probably won't be available forever.

Comment: thanks for your reply. nothing worked for me so far.